# Is it ok for Optional#map to change the state of the input parameter to the Function lambda?

Tags: java, java-8, monads, option-type

I have a piece of Java code which removes an element from a set contained in the input parameter to Optional#map

```
boolean ret = methodReturnsOptioanl()
                .map(project -> project.getDocIds().remove(docId))
                .orElse(false);
```

where project.getDocIds() returns a Set of string ids and is guaranteed to be not null.

I've tested it and works; ret is false if the Optional is empty or docId doesn't exist in the set.

However, is it ok for Optional#map to do this and alter the state of the member set and return the boolean result of the Set#remove operation?

I've searched around and can't find any definitive answer on this.

Comment: It’s up to you to decide whether the code is obvious enough to future readers (including your future self)…

Comment: You don't need an optional here imo.

Comment: Technically you don't **need** `Optional` anywhere, but this seems in line with the primary intended use case, a return value from a function that might otherwise return `null` (assuming `optionalVal` comes from a method call). The functional programmer in me is uncomfortable with a call to `map` modifying state. I would prefer something like in Remco's answer, but this is a style thing more than "right/wrong"

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I've updated the code to make clear the Optional is coming from a method call.

Comment: This question was closed incorrectly. While the (current) answers *do* rely heavily on opinion, the question seems to be seeking authoritative facts, rather than soliciting opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say no, the best way to do this is to map your `project` to the `docIds` assigned to your `project` Object and to then call the terminal operation `Stream#orElse`. This terminal operation should construct a new (Mutable) List/Collection, from which you can then remove the `docId`.

With that your code would look like the following:

```
boolean ret = optionalVal
              .map(Class::getDocIds)
              .orElse(new ArrayList<>())
              .remove(docId);
```

A more memory efficient solution would however be:

```
boolean ret = optionalVal
              .map(Class::getDocIds)
              .orElseGet(ArrayList::new)
              .remove(docId);
```

This has to do with the fact that the `Supplier` given to `Optional#orElseGet` only gets called when the `optionalVal` variable is empty. When you use `Optional#orElse`, this method will always be called and with that an empty (and possibly unnecassery) `ArrayList` will be constructed and loaded into the Heap. This means that when your Optional is not empty, you construct twice as many Objects as needed instead of just one.

**Explanation**

The `Stream#map` method is a intermediate operation which means that it transforms the Stream into another stream. This is not the case. For that, you can use the `orElse` operation as a terminal operation, which produces a `List`/`Object` as a result in order for you to remove your objectId.

**Explanation memory efficient solution**

The `Optional#orElseGet` only calls the `Supplier` when the value is **not** present. The following test was run to verify this:

```
public class TestTest {

    class TestOptional {

        public TestOptional(){
            System.out.println("TestOptional constructor called.. " + this);
        }

        List<String> getDocIds(){
            System.out.println("TestOptional#getDocIds called.. " + this);
            return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList("test"));
        }

        List<String> getEmptyDocIds(){
            System.out.println("TestOptional#getEmptyDocIds called.. " + this);
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {

        Optional<TestOptional> optionalVal = Optional.of(new TestOptional());
        Optional<TestOptional> optionalValEmpty = Optional.empty();

        boolean deleted = optionalVal
                .map(TestOptional::getDocIds)
                .orElse(new TestOptional().getEmptyDocIds())
                .remove("test");

        System.out.println("One: " + deleted);

        System.out.println("\n ### \n");

        boolean deletedTwo = optionalVal
                .map(TestOptional::getDocIds)
                .orElseGet(() -> new TestOptional().getEmptyDocIds())
                .remove("test");

        System.out.println("Two: " + deletedTwo);

        System.out.println("\n ### \n");

        boolean deletedThree = optionalValEmpty
                .map(TestOptional::getDocIds)
                .orElse(new TestOptional().getEmptyDocIds())
                .remove("test");

        System.out.println("Three: " + deletedThree);

        System.out.println("\n ### \n");

        boolean deletedFour = optionalValEmpty
                .map(TestOptional::getDocIds)
                .orElseGet(() -> new TestOptional().getEmptyDocIds())
                .remove("test");

        System.out.println("Four: " + deletedFour);

        assertThat(deleted).isTrue();
        assertThat(deletedTwo).isTrue();
        assertThat(deletedThree).isFalse();
        assertThat(deletedFour).isFalse();
    }
}
```

Output of test:

```
TestOptional constructor called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@28f67ac7
TestOptional#getDocIds called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@28f67ac7
TestOptional constructor called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@1a407d53
TestOptional#getEmptyDocIds called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@1a407d53
One: true

 ### 

TestOptional#getDocIds called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@28f67ac7
Two: true

 ### 

TestOptional constructor called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@3cda1055
TestOptional#getEmptyDocIds called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@3cda1055
Three: false

 ### 

TestOptional constructor called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@79b4d0f
TestOptional#getEmptyDocIds called.. test.TestTest$TestOptional@79b4d0f
Four: false
```

*However: This would not have too much of an impact, if this code is used for short time and not so frequently (as in amount of uses of method), as this method probably will be out of scope in no time. It's however still more work for the Garbage Collector which means unnecessary misuse of bytes of storage.*

Answer (score 5):

Is it okay to use `map()` this way? No, because `map()` expresses an intent to transform the optional element to a new type, and that isn't what you are doing.

While there is no *requirement* that `map()` operations are free of side-effects, and your original code will do what you want, it isn't doing what people expect from `map()`. Future readers might need a second look to grasp what your code is doing. I would suggest something more obvious:

```
var project = methodReturnsOptional();
boolean ret = project.isPresent() && project.get().getDocIds().remove(docId);
```